# How to edit the user created date?

Tags: users

For node, we can change the created date easily, what about user ? Is there any easy way or module that can expose this field for editing instead via database ? I have many old users to be keyed in again manually into drupal, so I need to change this date of creation at the time of creating the user.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this before, but if you have a module that loaded a user account, perhaps using [`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7), you can manually re-set the $account->created.  Clues given in the user_save() function.  Let me know how you get on...

code will look something like this:

```
$account = user_load($users_uid_here);
$account->created = $date_timestamp_here; // eg. REQUEST_TIME
user_save($account);
```

Comment: $user->created is a unix timestamp, not a formatted date string